# Get the top value of a column - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

Imagine a table like this:

[image: 1$ 2$ 3$ Water Snickers Sandwich Chewing Gums M&Ms Iced Tea]

In a different place I'd like to get the "price" of a "product".
(Refering to the "product" and returning the "price")

So far, I tried lookup, index - match and a few more things, but none of those have worked for me. :/

If someone knows how to do this, that'd be very helpful!!

Comment: HI, how do you select the product you wish to get the price ?

Comment: DId you try to make it with a Index + match formula ? https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/02/04/google-sheets-index-match/

Comment: Yeah I said that in the question. And the products are exist in a list, I just want the list to adjust whenever the price of a product changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`/`MAX`/ `COLUMN` functions:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1;;MAX((F2=$A$2:$C$3)*COLUMN($A$2:$C$3)))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't undestand how it works, but it works. So thank you very much!